# ¿función para descargar imagen funciona en servidor local pero en el servidor remoto no?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Tengo una función para descargar una imagen funciona en el servidor local pero en el servidor remoto no sirve

```
<div class="" id="paraDescargar" >
    <img class="sobre "  src="http://movilpublicidad.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/marco.png" alt="">
    <img class="sobre2 "  src="http://movilpublicidad.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/SUBE-TU-IMAGEN.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="debajo" id="preview" >

    </div>
</div>

<div class="contForm">
    <form class="formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" onchange="preview(this)" class="file-input" />
    </form> 
   <button id="save"> Guardar Imagen</button>
   <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#" class="formulario">Descargar</a>
</div>

function preview(e)
{
if(e.files && e.files[0])
{

    // Comprobamos que sea un formato de imagen
    if (e.files[0].type.match('image.*')) {

        // Inicializamos un FileReader. permite que las aplicaciones web lean 
        // ficheros (o información en buffer) almacenados en el cliente de forma
        // asíncrona
        // Mas info en: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader
        var reader=new FileReader();

        // El evento onload se ejecuta cada vez que se ha leido el archivo
        // correctamente
        reader.onload=function(e) {
            console.log(e.target.result);
            document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML="<img class='imagenDebajo' src='"+e.target.result+"' >";
        }

        // El evento onerror se ejecuta si ha encontrado un error de lectura
        reader.onerror=function(e) {
            document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML="Error de lectura";
        }

        // indicamos que lea la imagen seleccionado por el usuario de su disco duro
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.files[0]);
    }else{

        // El formato del archivo no es una imagen
        document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML="No es un formato de imagen";
    }
}
introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí}

<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="canvas2image.js"></script>



   $('#save').click(function(){
       var elm = $('#paraDescargar').get(0);
       var lebar = "700";
       var tinggi = "470";
       var type = "jpg";
       var filename = "movil_publicidad";
       html2canvas(elm).then(function(canvas){
            var canWidth = canvas.width;
            var canHeight = canvas.height;
            var img = Canvas2Image.convertToImage(canvas, canWidth, canHeight);
            //$('#preview').after(img);
            Canvas2Image.saveAsImage(canvas,lebar,tinggi,type,filename)
       })
   })
```

Comment: que error te indica en consola?

Comment: no aparece ningún error, solo que en el servidor local descarga la imagen y en servidor remoto la descarga es vacía.

Comment: Para solucionarlo en el servidor remoto las imágenes tienen que ser imágenes embebidas